# How to store and render a Pandas dataframe/CSV for each model entry (Django)?

Tags: django, pandas, django-models, django-templates

I have a model that represents a single patient. It stores information such as the `patient_name` (`CharField`), `weight` (`IntegerField`), `height` (`IntegerField`) etc.

I extended the save method `save(self, *args, **kwargs)` to perform a series of calculations/functions (e.g. calculate BMI) to save back to the model. For the extended `save()` method, it also runs a function that calculates weekly weight loss goals in pandas and saves to CSV (named by `patient_name`) in a `media` folder.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to display that CSV data back for each patient. Currently, I'm using the `DetailView` CBV to serve up a detail page for each patient with their new computed model fields (e.g. `<p>{{ object.patient_name }}'s calculated BMI is {{ object.bmi }}</p>`)

There are three ideas I have but I'm not sure if they will work or how to implement it.

1 - I could generate an HTML table instead of CSV, is there a way to render custom HTML snippets from a media folder based on a trait of the model or primarykey id `{% media|object.patient_name %}`?

2 - I could try to save the pd.DataFrame, CSV (or the string text representation of an HTML table) to a new model field (hidden/editable=False) and pass it through templating like `{{ object.html_table }}`. I'm just not sure if it is possible or secure to store and render HTML code from a TextField.

3 - I could try to save the CSV/df as an image in an `ImageField` and serve up the image. Ideally, there would be a model field like `ImageField` that would refer 1:1 to the CSV file (or HTML table representation) and allow Django templating to pass it through and render it.

Would appreciate some suggestions if anyone has tried something similar to this in the past or knows the best way to implement storing and rendering a table for each model entry/database row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most secure way, it seems a bit hacky, but it works. I basically went with the #2 approach

In my backend logic I just got the HTML string of the table representation of the dataframe like `html_table_str = df.to_html()` and then returned the string to my model `html_table_str`

mybackendlogic.py:

```py
def calculate_table(weight_kg, height_m):
    multiplier_df = pd.read_csv(MEDIA_ROOT + '\multipliers.csv')
    bmi = (weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
    total_df = (multiplier_df * bmi)
    html_table_str = total_df.to_html()
    return html_table_str
```

models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from .mybackendlogic import calculate_table

class DoFoo(models.Model):
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()
    html_table_str = models.TextField(editable=False)  # hidden in views

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.html_table_str = calculate_table(self.weight, self.height)
    super(DoFoo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then pass through `{{ object.html_table_str|safe }}` in your html template

detail.html:

```html
{% block content %}
<p class="">Here is your table, user </p>
{{ object.html_table_str|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```